# ListViews and large lists recovered from a remote service

Tags: java, android, mysql, sql

I need to implement a web service for a feed of videos and consume it with an Android client.

By the way my implementation was a method `getVideos(offset,quantity)` with a MySQL table that returns the result of the query `SELECT * FROM videos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT offset,quantity` where the id is an auto-incremental value.

But, since it is a very active feed I've detected the following erroneous case:

The database have the videos 1,2,3...10.

The Android client request the videos offset=0 , quantity=5 so the items 10,9,8,7,6 are returned. The user start to play some videos and in the meanwhile 5 new videos are published, so now the table contains the items 1,2,3...15 now. Then the user continues scrolling and, when the user reach the end of the list, the client attempts to request the next bundle: offset=5, quantity=5, but the same items are returned, appearing duplicates (or adding nothing) into the ListView.

What if the best approach for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want data to repeat then don't use `OFFSET`, use a where clause on id instead.
Check what's the last id you were given and then run a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id<:last_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,:quantity
```

Not only this guarantees the results will not repeat but also [it should actually be faster](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page) since the db won't have to calculate all the offset rows.

## UPDATE

How about getting a maximum value of id column when you make the first query and then adding to `WHERE` that all the results have to be lower or equal to that original value? That way you won't ever get duplicates unless you update some position. Better yet if you add a modification time column to your rows and use time of the first query. That way you won't show edited rows but at least they won't break the order.

```
SELECT * 
FROM videos 
WHERE mtime < :original_query_time 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT :offset, :quantitiy;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jakub, I forgot to mention that the service result is not necessary ordered by id DESC. Imagine for example a "popular" feed returning the result in positive_votes/votes order

Comment: @Addev Updated. If that won't work then your only chance are things like SQL cursors and if so then it would be better to allow for duplicates.